# conditionalPanel in Shiny: condition based on class of variable in a dataset

Tags: javascript, r, shiny

I'm building a Shiny app which contains various options for mapping/visualising data from a particular dataset. I have a `selectInput` where the user selects the variable from the dataset they would like to visualise.

I would like to have a `conditionalPanel` which displays when a user selects a *numeric* variable only.

I'm sure it's quite simple, but I'm having trouble writing the condition argument of `conditionalPanel` as I'm not familiar with Javascript. In R language, I could use `is.numeric()`, but I'm not familiar with how to do that in Javascript. I've tried `condition = "isNaN(input.variables) == FALSE"`, but I think this just tests whether the name of the variable is a number or not, not the data therein.

I'm aware that I could write a condition in R using a reactive expression on the server side as per [this tutorial](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/dynamic-ui.html), but I'd rather avoid it since it's more computationally intensive.

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Sample code below. To be clear, the radio buttons should display ONLY when the "nums" variable is selected (containing numeric data) but NOT when the "letters" variable is selected.

```
letters <- c("a","b","c")
nums <- 1:3
dat <- data.frame(letters,nums)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarPanel(
    selectInput("variables", h4("Pick variable to plot:"), choices = colnames(dat)),
    conditionalPanel( 
      condition = "isNaN(input.variables) == FALSE",
      radioButtons("seq_div", "Colours should be...", c("sequential", "divergent"))
    )
  ),
  mainPanel()
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Wouldn't you already know which variable in the dataframe is numeric?

Comment: It is `false` (small) however that doesnt fix it...

Comment: Fair point Pork Chop! It's true that with the dataset I'm working with right now, I know which columns are numeric. However eventually I would like users to be able to upload their own data which may be numeric or categorical, and my app will have to work out which is which and colour accordingly. Sorry for not making that clearer.

Also, yes you're right mRcSchwering! it should read "isNaN(input.variables) == false". My bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't know beforehand which columns are numeric (which I think is the case here) you can do:

```
letters <- c("a","b","c")
nums <- 1:3
num2 <- 4:6
dat <- data.frame(letters,nums, num2)

numeric_cols = paste("'",colnames(dat)[sapply(dat, is.numeric)],"'", collapse = ',', sep = '')

ui <- fluidPage(
    sidebarPanel(
        selectInput("variables", h4("Pick variable to plot:"), choices = colnames(dat)),
        conditionalPanel( 
            condition = paste0("[", numeric_cols, "].indexOf(input.variables) >= 0"),
            radioButtons("seq_div", "Colours should be...", c("sequential", "divergent"))
        )
    ),
    mainPanel()
)

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {
})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

It basically find which columns are numeric, paste them in a JS array form, and then check if the selected item is inside that array.